# irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk : sendMediaGroup can't send video without sound

Tags: php, telegram-bot

When I am trying to send a mp4 without sound (like a gif) with sendMediaGroup I get this error :

> "Bad Request: failed to send message #1 with the error message "Wrong
> file i (truncated...)"

But it work fine if the video has sound.

This is the code I am using :

```
$telegram = new Telegram\Bot\Api(api_key);
        $telegram
            ->setAsyncRequest(true)
            ->sendMediaGroup(['chat_id' => channel_id, 'media' => json_encode([
                ['type'=>'video' ,'media' => 'https://i.imgur.com/qAxrsIG.mp4', 'caption' => "Album caption"],
                ['type' => 'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg'],
                ['type' => 'photo' ,'media' => 'http://www.alcan5000.com/JPG/64Caliente.jpg']
            ])]);
```

I guess the telegram api see it as animation or something but is there a trick to bypass that ?

Comment: You probably need sendPhoto. Could you share the file?

Comment: sendPhoto is for image and its only for single file, you can try with with the one from my code, this one (no sound) will not work https://i.imgur.com/qAxrsIG.mp4, this one (sound) will work https://figtreefoundation.org/wp-content/uploads/2021/01/Video-Placeholder.mp4